# Turn off colors in Netware console?

Tags: unix, unix-shell, novell

I'm looking for a method of changing colors in default Novell Netware (OES) console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If absolutely nothing else comes up, you could try adding `-m` to the end of `$TERM` or setting it to `vt100` before running the console.